# How to implement a variable multidimensional array using int** array = new int*[n];?

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried this approach but I am getting error when I `cout <<vararr[i][j]<<endl;`
The problem I am trying to solve- [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

my code-

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int* variablesizedarr(int size){
    int* arr= new int [size];
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        cin >>arr[i];
    }
    /*I believe the problem is when I return the arr array*/
    return arr;
    
}

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n,q,size;
    cin >>n >>q;
    int** vararr= new int* [n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >>size;
        vararr[i]=variablesizedarr(size);
    }
    /*now printing the values to the console*/
    
    for(int k=0;k<q;k++){
        int i,j;
        cin >>i>>j;
        cout <<vararr[i][j]<<endl; /* definitely an error in this line because that's what the compiler say*/
    } 

    // deallocate the array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        delete [] vararr[i];
        
    }
    delete [] vararr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

edit1: error I am getting-

```
Compiler Message
Segmentation Fault
Error (stderr)
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 2655054]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004011f2 in main () at Solution.cpp:32
32          cout <<vararr[i][j]<<endl;
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

I know I could do this the way other people have done it, but I was not going to learn like that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the error in the question.

Comment: In `variablesizedarr` why don't you write to `arr[0]`?

Comment: Also, right now it's hard to reproduce this because we don't know what input you're providing. Can you replace all the `cin >> n >> q;` type stuff with hardcoded values and still experience the issue you're describing? If not can you at least tell us what input you're trying, what output you expect, and what output you're getting instead? "I am getting error" is very vague.

Comment: I have edited it to also mention the error I am getting.

Comment: @NathanPierson Oops. I doubt that is going to resolve the error. Let me try

Comment: @NathanPierson It did. Can you please add the answer so I can accept it or give you green tick? Thank you very much. I was doubting my understanding because I was not able to get the answer. Turns out an indexing mistake.

Comment: @NathanPierson Can you please explain why there is no need to give indirection in this cout line- cout <<vararr[i][j]<<endl; 
vararr is a pointer and to derefrence it we need to use * operator in front of vararr[i][j]
like this *vararr[i][j]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nathanpearson I was able to find the error in

```
int* variablesizedarr(int size){
    int* arr= new int [size];
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        cin >>arr[i];
    }
    /*I believe the problem is when I return the arr array*/
    return arr;
    
}
```

Here the initialization of i should be 0, not 1. I know it's a stupid mistake, but Hackerrank debugger is very bad in explaining the error so I was doubting my understanding. Anyway, this is another way to make a variable multidimensional array without using a vector.

Again, Thanks to Nathan for taking the time to understand my question.I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int** p = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p[i] = new int[m];
}
```

Comment: what if I get the value of p[i] from a function? Probably I am getting an error because of that. But I don't see anything wrong with my code. This is a unique approach so didn't find much on it.